# Establish MQTT using lwip gives routing error ( ERR_RTE)

Tags: tcp, mqtt, lwip

I'm using the latest lwip stable release 2.13 on STM32F4 target and trying to establish a MQTT connection.

I'm setting up the network interface as follow

```c
lwip_init();
netif_add(&my_netif, &myIP, &maskIP, &gwIP, NULL, netif_init_, netif_input);
netif_set_default(&my_netif);
netif_set_up(&my_netif);
```

And then calling MQTT as in the example from Dirk Ziegelmeier  [text](https://github.com/lwip-tcpip/lwip/blob/master/contrib/examples/mqtt/mqtt_example.c)

```c
mqtt_client = mqtt_client_new();

mqtt_set_inpub_callback(mqtt_client,
        mqtt_incoming_publish_cb,
        mqtt_incoming_data_cb,
        LWIP_CONST_CAST(void*, &mqtt_client_info));

mqtt_client_connect(mqtt_client,
        &mqtt_ip, MQTT_PORT,
        mqtt_connection_cb, LWIP_CONST_CAST(void*, &mqtt_client_info),
        &mqtt_client_info);
```

This returns ERR_RTE ( Routing problem.)

The error is happening in mqtt_client_connect()

When reading the code I couldn't find any binding between TCP stack ( created in mqtt_client_connect()) and the netif ?

So I added the binding in  `mqtt_client_connect()` in mqtt.c

```c
struct tcp_pcb *pcb;
pcb = (struct tcp_pcb *)client->conn->state;
tcp_bind_to_default_netif(pcb);
```

Just before

```c
/* Connect to server */
err = altcp_connect(client->conn, ip_addr, port, mqtt_tcp_connect_cb);
```

definition of `tcp_bind_to_default_netif()` in tcp.c

```c
void tcp_bind_to_default_netif(struct tcp_pcb *pcb){
    LWIP_ASSERT_CORE_LOCKED();
    if (netif_default != NULL) {
        pcb->netif_idx = netif_get_index(netif_default);
    } else {
        pcb->netif_idx = NETIF_NO_INDEX;
    }
}
```

Now I don't have the routing error and mqtt_client_connect() is exiting without any errors but no connection to my MQTT broker.

I'm not sure where the tcp and netif binding should be done ?

Any suggestions are very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the `mqtt_client_connect` function code in the version you mentioned (2.13) I noticed that the callbacks are wiped:

[git repo](https://github.com/lwip-tcpip/lwip/blob/6ca936f6b588cee702c638eee75c2436e6cf75de/src/apps/mqtt/mqtt.c#L1304C1-L1306C29)

```
/* Wipe clean */
memset(client, 0, sizeof(mqtt_client_t));
```

This issue is already fixed In the branch 'master'.

So configuring the callbacks after calling `mqtt_client_connect` maybe will solve your problem.